# How to keep umlaut while transliterating in PHP?

Tags: php, diacritics, transliteration

I have to transliterate like this:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", transliterator_transliterate("Any-Latin;Latin-ASCII", $string));
```

because of cyrillic letters, and it's working fine for cyrillic, but I had to realise, unfortunately all german letters like ü are going to be replaced with u as well, and this is not wanted. I have searched quite a lot, but found nothing really helpful. Now I have checked both functions separate and it turns out, both transliterator_transliterate() and iconv() change german characters... Is there a way to prevent german letters to be changed during transliteration and iconv()?

Comment: You need to target a charset other than ASCII, because ASCII cannot represent umlaute. Choose a charset which can.

Comment: Or to say that another way, why do you want to transliterate to ASCII but also include non-ASCII characters? Are you perhaps wanting Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 instead?